# SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in D:\practise\nodejs\nodejs-demo\views\index.html while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I try to change the engne view from .ejs to .html something goes wrong ! after search the net, I don't find the answer. here are the problems :
like this:

```
Express
500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in D:\practise\nodejs\nodejs-demo\views\index.html while compiling ejs
   at Function (native)
   at Object.Template.compile (D:\practise\nodejs\nodejs-demo\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:455:12)
   at Object.compile (D:\practise\nodejs\nodejs-demo\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:288:16)
   at handleCache (D:\practise\nodejs\nodejs-demo\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:147:16)
   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\practise\nodejs\nodejs-demo\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:348:14)
   at View.render (D:\practise\nodejs\nodejs-demo\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:76:8)
   at Function.app.render (D:\practise\nodejs\nodejs-demo\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:561:10)
   at ServerResponse.res.render (D:\practise\nodejs\nodejs-demo\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:845:7)
   at exports.index (D:\practise\nodejs\nodejs-demo\routes\index.js:7:7)
   at callbacks (D:\practise\nodejs\nodejs-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
```

here are some file content:

> app.js

```js
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var ejs = require('ejs');

var app = express();




// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//使用html 扩展
app.engine('.html',ejs.__express);
app.set('view engine','html');

app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

> header.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><%=: title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
    <!-- <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> -->
</head>
<body screen_capture_injected="true">
```

> footer.html

```html
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> index.html

```html
<!-header-->
<% include  header.html %>

    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>


<% include footer.html %>
```

> environment

```
node v0.12.2 npm 2.7.4 express 3.20.2
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says you have an unexpected token (a colon) in index.html.  You have this:

```
<%=: title %>
```

Remove the colon.